# How can I see if a list of tuples contains a specific tuple by knowing the values in this tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I am fairly new to python and therefore, although I have been trying to find a solution to this problem since hours, I cant! I have a list of tuples called *list_of_tuples* and then another list of tuples which is called *finalTuple*
and to which I have appended two tuples. What I wanna do is read all of the tuples from the list_of_tuples and figure out if there is already an identical tuple in the list.
If there is one I wanna print a message in the console which indicates that otherwise just append the tuple in the finalTuple. Could someone help me with that? I have tried the following code but it doesnt work:

```
list_of_tuples = [ ("a","b","c"),
    ("a","b","c"),
    ("a","b","d"),
     ("a","b","d"),
    ("i","k","l")
]

first_tuple = ("a","b","c")
second_tuple= ("a","b","d")
finalTuple = []
finalTuple.append(first_tuple)
finalTuple.append(second_tuple)

for i in range(len(list_of_tuples)):
   # print(listtt[i])
    if not(any((list_of_tuples[i]) in j for j in finalTuple)) :
       key_value = []
       key_value.append(list_of_tuples[i])
       finalTuple.append(tuple(key_value))
       print("The tuple is appended to the list")
    if (any((list_of_tuples[i]) in j for j in finalTuple)) :
       print("The value already exists")
```

The output I am getting on the console is:

```
PS C:\Users\andri\PythonProjects\mypyth> py test.py
The tuple is appended to the list
The value already exists
The value already exists
The tuple is appended to the list
The value already exists
The value already exists
The tuple is appended to the list
The value already exists
```

Comment: Not sure I am following the output you are looking for. After the loop is completed, should `finalTuple` not contain any of the tuples in `list_of_tuples`? In other words, you can only append tuples to `finalTuple` that are not already contained in `list_of_tuples`?

Comment: just append all tuple to `final_tuple` and then do `final_tuple = list(set(final_tuple))`

Comment: you want to display the tuple which is always in the list?

Comment: @benvc yeah exactly

Comment: @Frenchy what do you mean?

Comment: i missunderstand you maybe, i ask you if you just want to display the content of tuple?

Comment: use dictionary to know if it is in the final_tuple or not

Comment: Why are you using `in` at all? For tuples `i` and `j`, `i in j` is true if some *element* of `j` is `i`, not if `i` is a "subtuple" of `j`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lot = [("a","b","c"),
    ("a","b","c"),
    ("a","b","d"),
     ("a","b","d"),
    ("i","k","l")]

ft = [("a","b","c"),("a","b","d")]
```

Use `in` or `not in` for [membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-operations)    .

```
>>> for thing in lot:
...     if thing in ft:
...         print(f'{thing} in ft')
...     else:
...         ft.append(thing)


('a', 'b', 'c') in ft
('a', 'b', 'c') in ft
('a', 'b', 'd') in ft
('a', 'b', 'd') in ft
>>> ft
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('i', 'k', 'l')]
>>>
```

---

Or [use sets for membership testing](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset).

```
>>> set(lot).difference(ft)
{('i', 'k', 'l')}
>>> ft.extend(set(lot).difference(ft))
>>> ft
[('a', 'b', 'c'), ('a', 'b', 'd'), ('i', 'k', 'l')]
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `if` block that checks if the value already exists takes place after the `if` block that checks if it doesn't, append the value to the list, so the former is always `True` since the value would be appended to the list even if it did not. You should use an `else` block for the opposite condition instead. Moreover, to check if a tuple already exists in a list of tuples, you can simply use the `in` operator instead:

```
for i in range(len(list_of_tuples)):
   if list_of_tuples[i] in finalTuple:
       print("The value already exists")
   else:
       finalTuple.append(list_of_tuples[i])
       print("The tuple is appended to the list")
```